# It is possible to convert qubits to bits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, conventions

I was wonder if it is possible to do mathematical operations like bits operations but with qubits. Is there a way to convert qubits to bits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quantum Computing Power Advantages](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52205/) or [Qubit (Qdit) equivalence with bits/bytes/Kbytes/](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71400/)

Comment: The problem is usually that your qubits become bits when you don't want them to.

Answer (score 0):

When measured, a qbit, just like a bit, can only have two possible states- 1 or 0. However, it can hold more information than a bit because it can also be in a superposition of both the states. At it's maximum a qbit can hold 2 bits of information.

However, that is not the point of quantum computing at all! Quantum computers aren't supposed to magically increase your hard-drive to a million terabyte. Their magic lies in the insane parallel processing power it will provide

Comment: To be more precise, quantum computers are not like parallel computers, which try all inputs and returns all valid outputs. Quantum computing algorithms work because they initialize the input as the superposition of all possible inputs, and the constructive and destructive interferences during the algorithm help return one single valid output.

Answer (score -1):

Qubits and bits are fundamentally different, though they're analogous. Usually, there's no *conversion*... you can't hook up a quantum computing system to the middle of a conventional processor and watch your quantum computer take over, so there's no real meaningful conversion.

But with the attempt to talk about the similarities, you can saying that qubits, like normal bits will represent 0 or 1. But in some ways, like when you're talking about the more direct involvement of quantum effects, you'll need 2 qubits to demarkate what 1 ordinary bit does.

Comment: "_more direct involvement of quantum effects_" can you make that a bit more specific?