# How does QC work?

Tags: quantum-computer

I watched this video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=g_IaVepNDT4

That says QC has 2 to the N bits. And that is somehow useful. But they don’t say why lots of bits can be useful. Can anyone please explain how it works in simple terms?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12460/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Yes that link was helpful thanks. Although they showed formulas, which is a bad way to learn something. Einstein said scientists don’t think in formulas. Which is sad why people resort to them when teaching.